# How do you list all apps in an adb backup .ab file?

Tags: adb, restore

I did a backup of my phone and produced an .ab file

> ```
> G:\phonebk>adb backup -apk -shared -all -f backup.ab
> WARNING: adb backup is deprecated and may be removed in a future release
> Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation...
>
> G:\phonebk>
> ```

How do you list all apps in an adb backup .ab file?

I have read that `adb restore com.identifier.name.ab` will restore a particular app, but suppose I want to see the name of the app,  And moreso, the names of all the apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Restore individual apps from a full backup

`adb restore` always restores the full content of an Android backup file. Therefore if you want to restore apps individually you have to make individual backups so that you get one backup files per app:

```
adb backup <packagename> -f <packagename>.ab
```

Alternatively you can use [Android Backup Extractor (abe)](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) to convert an Android backup file to an TAR archive, modify that archive (e.g. delete all data and apps you don't want to restore) and then convert the TAR archive back to an Android backup via abe.

#### Getting the package name of an app without using a Android device

If you want to know what package name has a particular app you can simply use [Google Play Store web site](https://play.google.com/store/apps). Search for the app you want to know the package name of - for example [Twitter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android).

Check the address bar of your web browser and you will see `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twitter.android`.

The package name comes after the `id=` section (it ends at the next `&` character or the end of the address). Therefore the package name of twitter is `com.twitter.android`.